# cleaning dict keys in nested dict of dicts & lists of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dict with list of dicts as well, and some of my keys have special chars. What is the best way to remove those special chars from the keys.

The below that I have attempted works on dicts of dicts, but how can i extend it to take care of list of dicts as well.

```
>>> a={"@pipeline": "start",  "@args": "-vv", "@start": "1598331637", "@info": {"@pipeline_stage": "tasks","@taskbegin": [{"@task": "1", "@time": "1598331638"}, {"@task": "2", "@time": "1598331638"}, {"@task": "3", "@time": "1598331638"}]}}
>>> a
{'@pipeline': 'start', '@args': '-vv', '@start': '1598331637', '@info': {'@pipeline_stage': 'tasks', '@taskbegin': [{'@task': '1', '@time': '1598331638'}, {'@task': '2', '@time': '1598331638'}, {'@task': '3', '@time': '1598331638'}]}}
>>> def _clean_keys(d):
...     return {''.join(filter(str.isalnum, k)): _clean_keys(v) for k, v in d.items()} if isinstance(d, dict) else d
... 
>>> _clean_keys(a)
{'pipeline': 'start', 'args': '-vv', 'start': '1598331637', 'info': {'pipelinestage': 'tasks', 'taskbegin': [{'@task': '1', '@time': '1598331638'}, {'@task': '2', '@time': '1598331638'}, {'@task': '3', '@time': '1598331638'}]}}
>>>
```

As you can see, the taskbegin list is not cleaned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using recursion

**Ex:**

```
a={"@pipeline": "start",  "@args": "-vv", "@start": "1598331637", "@info": {"@pipeline_stage": "tasks","@taskbegin": [{"@task": "1", "@time": "1598331638"}, {"@task": "2", "@time": "1598331638"}, {"@task": "3", "@time": "1598331638"}]}}
def _clean_keys(d):
    res = {}
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():   
            k = ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, k))      
            if isinstance(v, list):                   #Check if type of value is list
                res[k] = [_clean_keys(i) for i in v]  #use recursion
            else:
                res[k]= _clean_keys(v)
            
    else:
        res = d           
        
    return res

print(_clean_keys(a))
```

**Output:**

```
{'args': '-vv',
 'info': {'pipelinestage': 'tasks',
          'taskbegin': [{'task': '1', 'time': '1598331638'},
                        {'task': '2', 'time': '1598331638'},
                        {'task': '3', 'time': '1598331638'}]},
 'pipeline': 'start',
 'start': '1598331637'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works fine

> **Code**

```
def clean_dict(val):
    if type(val) == list:
        return clean_list(val)
    if type(val) == dict:
        return {clean(k) : clean_dict(v) for k, v in val.items()}
    return val

def clean_list(val):
    return [clean_dict(v) for v in val]

def clean(val):
   ''.join([c for c in val if c.isalnum()])
```

> **Output**

```
a={"@pipeline": "start",  "@args": "-vv", "@start": "1598331637", "@info": {"@pipeline_stage": "tasks","@taskbe
gin": [{"@task": "1", "@time": "1598331638"}, {"@task": "2", "@time": "1598331638"}, {"@task": "3", "@time": "1
598331638"}]}}

clean_dict(a)
Out[8]:
{'pipeline': 'start',
 'args': '-vv',
 'start': '1598331637',
 'info': {'pipelinestage': 'tasks',
  'taskbegin': [{'task': '1', 'time': '1598331638'},
   {'task': '2', 'time': '1598331638'},
   {'task': '3', 'time': '1598331638'}]}}
```